# Showing (x,y) coordinates of a straight line

Tags: plotting

In the following plot `Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, LabelStyle -> {15}]`, I want to highlight points (0.4,0.4) and (0.6,0.6)  as given below (which was done in Paint application). How can this be done in *Mathematica*?[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

pts = {x, x} /. {{x -> 0.4}, {x -> 0.6}};
```

Use [`Epilog`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html)

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"},
 LabelStyle -> {15},
 Epilog -> {
   Orange,
   AbsolutePointSize[6],
   Point[pts],
   Dashed,
   Line[{{#[[1]], 0}, #, {0, #[[2]]}}] & /@
    pts}]
```

[image]